# Windows phone. Isoled storage. One file or multiple small files

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I'm writing a little application on Windows phone. 
User saves  some info (abstract class Result  with 10-15 properties+ derived classes with new properties)   in Isolated Storage. Also he can watch history of previous results + he can delete some not needed results.(it can be 100 and more  previos results)

Should i use one file (read it  in Launching Event and write it in Deactivated event) or should i store every new result in separate file?
Should i use XmlSerialization or DataContractJsonSerializer?

Comment: If the data is important, I would recommend persisting it to Isolated Storage in regular intervals, in addition to Deactivated. There isn't a guarantee that your app will always get the Deactivated Event (OS freeze, App Crash, etc), so it is possible that your users could lose data.

Answer (score 1):

I think one file would be sufficient if the data saved are not too big. Otherwise the multiple file approach is the way to go, but should probably be backed up with some kind of summary file, that would contain previews of single results so that they don't have to be read all when you display some kind of list.
The best solution would be to use a local SQL Compact database, beacuse that would give you the best performance when dealing with data, but would also require some additional coding.